# How can I read an encrypted text from a file and decrypt it?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, java

I have some account info that is being encrypted and written to a file like this:

```
//imports here
public class Main 

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            String text = "this text will be encrypted";

            String key = "Bar12345Bar12345";

            //Create key and cipher
            Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

            //encrypt text
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
            write(new String(encrypted));

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void write(String message) {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {

            String data = message;

            File file = new File(FILENAME);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }


            fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write(data);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                if (bw != null)
                    bw.close();

                if (fw != null)
                    fw.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

So the contents of the file is one string without any breaks in between. If I wanted to decrypt the string, I would do this:

```
String key = "Bar12345Bar12345";
Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
byte[] encrypted = text.getBytes(); 
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
System.err.println(decrypted);
```

This works fine as long as `byte[] encrypted` is the same as used as in the encrypting process, but when I try to read the encrypted text from the file using a FileReader and a BufferedReader and change it into a byte using `lines.getByte()` it throws the exception

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

Comment: This is 2017, try **try-with-resources** instead of trying to close the resources yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Compare the cipher text from the encrypting process with the cipher text from lines.getByte() before you try to do any decryption.  They are most likely different. Try reading the entire file into a byte[] first before decrypting it.   Symmetric ciphers need to do their work on blocks of the same size, in this case 16 bytes.

I would also be remiss if I didn't comment on some of the poor protocol choices.

1. Hard coded key - Your encryption key should never be hard-coded in your application.  If you ever need to change your encryption key, you are not able to do so.  If your application is distributed to end users, it's easy for them to recover the key using an application like *strings*.
2. You are using [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#ECB) as your mode of operation. ECB has several ways it can be attacked, such as block shuffling, which can allow an attacker to decrypt data without having the encryption key.

Encryption is hard to get right on your own.  Consider solving your problem a different way.

Comment: I solved the issue by instead of converting to string before writing and reading, writing and reading the byte[] directly. 1. Isn't an issue since this is a server-side application, but how would I solve 2?

Comment: 1.  Is still a problem.  If a developer ever leaves your team on bad terms, or a server is mis-configured, or a bug in your application or another application on the server allows for read access to the file system, your key is compromised.  The easiest way to fix this is to set the encryption key in some sort of config file.  2. can be fixed by using a different mode of operation such a CBC, CTR,  etc, but you still need to follow the proper protocol.  (choosing the IV properly, etc.)  Encryption is very hard to get right.  Are you sure there is not an out of the box solution you can use?

Comment: I now switched to CBC mode, but how would I use such a config file? I'm on linux

Comment: The config file is going to depend on your envionment.  For example ASP.net uses a web.config file.  Your Java system will have it's own.  I think you're still not hearing me on this one, though. You really don't want to roll your own crypto.  Switching to CBC you need to make sure you're not vulnerable bit flipping attacks, and any other attacks which can be performed against CBC.  Are you sure you can't do something else like write the file to disk, encrypt it using GPG, and then performing a secure delete?  Or better yet, not write this file at all?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to treat your `encrypted` array contents as (platform encoded) text, while it is not - it consists of random bytes.

You either need to create a binary file by writing the contents of `encrypted` to it directly. That or you can create a text file by first encoding `encrypted` to base64.

Currently you are trying to read lines, but there aren't any. And if there are some line endings in there they will be stripped from the ciphertext before those bytes can be decrypted.

If you perform `new String(encrypted)` then it is also possible that you lose part of your data, as unsupported encodings are removed from the string without warning.

---

Note that the word "ciphertext" is a bit misleading; modern ciphers such as AES handle binary data, not text.